# Trying to do matrix-vector and matrix-matrix multiplication using loops in python

Tags: python, numpy, loops, matrix-multiplication

Here is the code I have, but I keep receiving error:

```
import numpy as n
  

mat=n.arrary([(2,3),(4,5)])
vect=n.array([1,2])

def mat_vect_mult(mat,vect):
    
    res=n.array([0,0])
    for i in range(len(mat)):
        for j in range(len(mat[0])):
            res[i][j]+=[i][j]*vect[j]
    return res

mat1=n.arrary([(2,3),(4,5)])
mat2=n.arrary([(2,3),(4,5)])

def mat_mat_mult(mat1,mat2):
    
    res=n.array(((0,0),(0,0)))
    for i in range(len(mat1)):
            for j in range(len(mat2[0])):
                for k in range(len(mat2)):
                    res[i][j]+=mat1[i][k]*mat2[k][j]
    return res
```

Comment: If you get an error, please share the error message. And please fix your formatting, the code highlighting is obviously broken.

Comment: Do you know that `numpy` already has a couple of functions that do matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion: When you import *Numpy* import it as **np**,
just as all the world does it.

To multiply an array by a vector, define your function as:

```
def mat_vect_mult(mat, vect):
    res = np.zeros_like(mat)
    for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
        for j in range(mat.shape[1]):
            res[i][j] += mat[i][j] * vect[j]
    return res
```

Your code contains *arrary* (drop last *r*).
You also failed to put the array name after *+=*.
I also changed the way to create *res* and ranges in both loops.

Then run `mat_vect_mult(mat, vect)` getting:

```
array([[ 2,  6],
       [ 4, 10]])
```

The same result you could get running `mat * vect` (each row in *mat*
is multiplied by *vect*).

To mutiply two matrices, change your function to:

```
def mat_mat_mult(mat1, mat2):
    res = np.zeros_like(mat)
    for i in range(mat1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(mat2.shape[1]):
            for k in range(mat1.shape[1]):
                res[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j]
    return res
```

I changed the way *res* is created and ranges of all loops:

- number of rows in *mat1*,
- number of column in *mat2*,
- length of a row in *mat1* (an also length of a column in *mat2*).

Your code will work only for arrays of shape (2, 2).

Then run: `mat_mat_mult(mat1, mat2)` getting:

```
array([[16, 21],
       [28, 37]])
```

The same result you could get running `mat1 @ mat2`.